# Wrapped union fails with "Argument of type... is not assignable to type... " - Why?

Tags: typescript, types, union

I am trying to wrap a Bull.js queue inside my own class (for encapsulation and further processing, etc).  When wrapping the Bull Queue instance, tsc fails with Argument of type 'string | ((job: Job, done: Function) => void) | ((job: Job) => Promise)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Compile works if I remove "|string" from the wrapping method's `callback:` signature.

The actual code: (this fails)

```
    async process(name: string, callback: ((job: Job<any>, done: Function) => void) | ((job: Job<any>) => Promise<any>) | string, concurrency = 1): Promise<void> {
        await this.queue.process(name, concurrency, callback)
    }
```

This works:

```
    async process(name: string, callback: ((job: Job<any>, done: Function) => void) | ((job: Job<any>) => Promise<any>), concurrency = 1): Promise<void> {
        await this.queue.process(name, concurrency, callback)
    }
```

By intuition, I expected that wrapping a function and mirroring it's paremeter signatures would obviously compile.

Why did my "fix" work?  And why did the original fail?  Your answer will help me understand union types!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a [mcve] (it relies on thirty-party typings you haven't included here); so any answer I give would just be a guess.  My guess is that the typings for `Queue.process` are [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and none of the overloads accept the full union type.  That's a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).  There are ways to deal with that, but I don't want to spend too much time on a guess about what your issue is.  Good luck!